Shouldn't Electric potential always equal infinity?
Electric potential at a point P is defined as being the work done to move a unit charge from a seperate reference point to that point P, and we like to choose the reference to point to be at infinity. 
But work is force times distance, so if distance is infinite, work done is infinite. Thus the electric potential should always be infinity.

Can anyone explain what the flaw is in my reasoning?

‘Force times distance’ is a baby definition applicable only for constant forces (i.e ones which are not changing from point to point).
The real definition involves an integral: $\int_{\gamma}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{l}$, the line-integral of the force dotted with the line element along a path $\gamma$. It is very possible to have improper integrals (e.g when $\gamma$ has infinite arclength) but still have finite integral (as long as the force vanishes sufficiently rapidly). The underlying fact here is that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$ is finite. If you know what this means, good, if not, just note my first sentence that the definition you gave is only for constant forces, which is not the case for the electric (or Newtonian gravitational) force.

Thank you! But, why does the integration limit go from 1 to infinity instead of zero to infinity? With 1 to infinity, we stop calculating the work done when the unit charge is 1 unit away from P. But we want the work in bringing unit charge to where it is zero units away from P.

@lylehunder. show me a physical charge we manipulate that has zero dimensions generally a spherically charged  metal for ex. acts like a point charge, but we arent getting closer than the container that itself is charged (for example)

@lylehunder. once upon a time a classical calculation of the size of an electron was performed by setting the energy of the electric field equal to the rest mass energy and solving for radius. (it wasnt right, but was cool)

@lylehunder if we work with a 1D analogy then $x=0$ is the location of the charge $Q$ which ‘sets up’ the electric field. We then imagine moving a ‘test charge’ $q$ from $x=+\infty$ to $x=1$. Or really you can think of moving a test charge from $x=+\infty$ to $x=r$ for any positive $r>0$, and again $\int_r^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2},dx$ is finite. Of course if we tried to move the test charge all the way to the location of the charge $Q$ setting up the electric field, then we get $\infty$ in this classical computation.

$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2},dx$ = 1 for anyone wondering.

^ hence by a change of variables (or direct evaluation) one can immediately deduce $\int_r^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2},dx=\frac{1}{r}$.

@lylehunder: "But we want the work in bringing unit charge to where it is zero units away from P." - the integral is set up so that the charge itself is at zero, and P is where you stop integrating (see comment by peek-a-boo above for details).

@peek-a-boo So when the definition talked about moving the test charge to P,  it meant moving to within r units of P?

@lylehunder What’s your definition of $P$? Are you moving the test charge from infinity to the point $P$? If that’s how you’re defining it then in terms of my 1D example, the point $P$ corresponds to $x=r$. The origin of my coordinate system $x=0$ is where the “actual” charge is that sets up the field. So $r$ is the distance from the actual charge to the test charge. Please reread what I wrote in the comment and draw a picture.
